# How to change data of listview inside a listview dynamically - UWP?

Tags: listview, data-binding, uwp

I am having some issues when I implement the data of listview inside listview.
I arranged all data inside listview

Parent Listview

```
  Child Listview  - - ->>

  Child Listview  - - ->>

  ...
```

I want to change Child Listview data dynamically.

After I get data from the api I can't show it on UI because it is not updated.

Please explain me how I can make this work perfectly.

Regards, RM.

Comment: What are you binding the child ListView to?   Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged when the data for the child listview is updated?

Comment: No I am using ObservableCollection variable for child list.

Comment: Make sure the observableCollection variable uses INotifyProperyChanged when the value changes so the UI knows to update